# setState callback is not firing after state change

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that I need executing after I have set the state of something. I'm using setStates callback function like so to call it:

```
setState({
    myState:myState
},secondFunction())

secondFunction = () => {
    console.log(this.state.myState);
}
```

When my callback function has the brackets: `()` the console will log undefined or nothing but when I remove the brackets from the call back like so it seems to work:

```
setState({
    myState:myState
},secondFunction)
```

I'm new to React so if someone could explain to me why having the brackets makes a different in the order in which the function is called that would be very helpful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reason is, you want a `function` to get called once `setState` completes it task, means it expect a function but when you used `()` means you are not passing a `function`, you are calling a `function`.

Other ways of writing same thing is:

```
setState({
    myState:myState
}, () => secondFunction())

setState({
    myState:myState
}, function(){ secondFunction() })
```

> Difference between secondFunction and secondFunction() :

`secondFunction` will **return a function body** but `secondFunction()` will return the **result of that function**.

Check this snippet:

```js
function abc(){
   return 'Hello'
}

console.log("body", abc);

console.log("result", abc());
```

Answer (score 1):

`setState` expects a function as callback.

If you add the parenthesis `()` you are calling the function `secondFunction` and passing whatever it returns as second argument to `setState`. Your function doesn't return anything, hence the `undefined` or `nothing`.

What you want to do is pass the function itself (so it can be called later), which is done without the parenthesis.